# ¿Cómo se pueden habilitar varias cuentas para Git?

Tags: git

He visto varias preguntas similares, pero ninguna da una respuesta sencilla.
La idea es tener un cliente git en mi PC y poder crear dos o más usuarios, para hacer commits sobre el mismo repositorio.

Comment: A ver.. tu idea no es tener un cliente.. si no que en cada repo puedas hacer commits con distintos usuarios? o hacer commit al mismo repo y elegir con cual usuario hacerlo?

Comment: Eso es, quisiera saber como poder tener varias cuentas para trabajar en un mismo repositorio en el mismo PC. Por ejemplo, crear dos usuarios (especificar correo y nombre), luego, con esos usuarios, hacer commits pero no a la vez. Un día hace un usuario y otro día hace otro. Así, si hay 10 commits por ejemplo, poder ver cual hizo cada uno.

Comment: Para esto sería mejor crear un servidor (o utilizar GitHub o GitLab), pero quería saber si era posible hacerlo en local sobre un solo PC con varios usuarios.

Answer (score -1):

Con un cliente git no tiene sentido. Lo que necesitas, si quieres compartir un desarrollo, es un [servidor git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Git-en-el-Servidor-Configurando-Git-en-un-servidor): una vez configurado, todos los usuarios que quieras podrán hacer [pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull) y [fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) para sincronizar los cambios del resto de usuarios.

Y crear sus propias ramas para trabajar, integrar los cambios en la rama principal, etc.